# jquery result is not coming even evrything is correct

Tags: jquery

The below piece of code is not giving any expected output. I tried many time to get the exact output but there is no use. Please let me know why this happening and where i have made a mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>My try</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("#a").val();
    var b = $("#b").val();   
    $("#bt1").on("click", function(){
        var sum = a + b;
        alert(sum);         
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="a" name="option"> 
   <input type="text" id="b" name="task"> 
<input id="bt1" type="button" value="click here"></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the value **before** the button is clicked. When you call `.val()` it returns a string which is **not** changed when the actual value of the input is changed.

When you click, the values are still the same values so you get the wrong output.

Instead, you can save the elements in a variable and get the value when you click the button.

This should work like a charm:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("#a");
    var b = $("#b");

    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        var sum = parseInt(a.val(), 10) + parseInt(b.val(), 10);
        alert(sum);
    })
});
```

---

As A. Wolff mentioned, because `.val()` returns strings, adding them is actually concatenating. So you have to force the values to a number first, hence the `parseInt()`.

Comment: you are concatenating strings here, you have to convert input values to number

Comment: Using parseInt(), you should always set radix in case of: `parseInt(a.val(),10)`

Answer (score 1):

- Mistake 1: Trying to retrieve the value before event call, so value is retrieved as soon as the page loads and when both text boxes are empty.
- Mistake 2: you want `sum` but you are just concatenating two `strings` not `int` to perform addition first `parse` them to `int` through `parseInt()`

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click", function(){
      var a = $("#a").val();
      var b = $("#b").val();   
      var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
      alert(sum);         
  })
  })
  ```

Comment: Maybe numbers are not only integers. Using `+` would convert it to number

Comment: got your first point they could be float also but i think he got the point and use the right `parse` acc. to his requirements. Didn't get you second statement `Using + will convert it to number`, can you explain a bit?

Comment: `var a = +$("#a").val();`  `a` is a number (integer or float doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mb7EB/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
        var a = +$("#a").val();
        var b = +$("#b").val();
        var sum = a + b;
        alert(sum);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy!

You have done two things wrong:

First of all, you should put put getters into "click" function.

```
 $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        var a = $("#a").val();
        var b = $("#b").val();
```

And secound of all, Jquery by default gets an string from value, so you should convert variables (a and b) to integer by `parseInt()`

And [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TMRsP/1/)